# Handling Either and ST monads

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

Let's say I have the following functions:

```
checkA :: a -> Either err b
checkA = undefined

checkB :: b -> ST s (Either err c)
checkB = undefined

check :: a -> ST s (Either err c)
check a = either (return . Left) checkB (checkA a)
```

Is there any way to write `check` such that it doesn't require using `return . Left`? Usually I'd do something like `>>=`, but in this case the return of `checkB` is wrapped inside another state monad, so it doesn't work. The other constraint is that `checkB` should only run if `checkA a` evaluates to `Right`, and should just fail with the error on `Left`

To generalize, are there any standard approaches to using nested monads?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Do you actually intend to use concrete types 'A', 'B' and 'Err'? If that's the case, your `check` function will not type-check.

Comment: If you want to get rid of `either` instead of `return`, I think `check = (return . checkA) >=> checkB` is equivalent.

Comment: @theindigamer I will update my question. I do want to use concrete types but they are actually `A`, `B`, `C`, and `Err`. The use of generics isn't clear here

Comment: Are you looking for Control.Monad.Trans.Except? If you had an `ExceptT err (ST s) a` instead of composing the monads manually, you could write `throwE` instead of `return . Left`.

Comment: @amalloy that certainly looks better. It just looks to me that whenever I have something like `either` where I don't deal with one side, there should be a better way of writing things. Even with `either throwE ...`, it might be redundant. I'm trying to look for a general solution with nested monads, where the snippet above is my actual usage. Another example is if I had a function dealing with `Either a (Maybe b)`

Comment: @chepner Your solution looks better as well. I will test it out in a bit; didn't occur to me to use `return` with `checkA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `ExceptT`:

```
checkA :: a -> Either err b
checkA = undefined

checkB :: b -> ExceptT err (ST s) c
checkB = undefined

check :: a -> ExceptT err (ST s) c
check a = except (checkA a) >>= checkB
-- or
check = except . checkA >=> checkB
```

`except` turns `Either err b` into `Monad m => ExceptT err m b`, and then you can do everything else in the `ExceptT err (ST s)` monad.

As a general rule, `ExceptT` is a great way to work with monadic actions that may fail when you *usually* want to bail on failure. The main exception is when the underlying monad is `IO`, in which case it's more common to use the built-in exception features from `Control.Exception`.

Of course, if you only need *one* monadic bind, `ExceptT` seems a bit like overkill, but once you need more it definitely makes sense.